# How to close the continues Error window 'String or Binary data would be truncated. The statement has been terminated"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, bulkinsert, sql-server-2014-express

I tried to insert 9000+ data in a single shot into a table using Edit option, but it is throwing the below error,

[image]

But my problem is, I'm not able to close the window as it is continuously coming for all the 9000+ rows one by one. 
I tried to close that window using Task Manager as well, but it is not closed. 
How can I close this window as it is not allowing me to do other task in SSMS.

Comment: @PrabhatG Yes I know but pressing ESC for 9000 rows, how it is possible?

Comment: No, I meant tapping it a couple of times will automatically close it. Else close `ssms.exe` from task manager to shut down sql server management studio

Comment: @PrabhatG i pressed it for more than 100 times sir. So also i closed the particular task in Task Manager. Do i need ti close the complete ssms to close this single window?

Comment: Kindly wait for someone with more experience to comment.

Comment: Task Manager, "Details" tab, find "ssms.exe", kill it, promise to never try to bulk insert through the API again but use the import/export data wizard instead. (Last step optional but recommended.)